# How to add transparent button inside image with pop-up menu

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio, aspbutton

Im having this image in one of my pages
[image]

I want to create the middle house "clickable" or something like transparrent or hidden button over it, so when i click on the house it will pop-up a small menu with "Go inside" or "Cancel" options.
So far i have only this code

```
 <div class="image-holder" style="padding-left: 1px">
                    <img src="../images/city.jpg" />
                    <div>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I tried moving the button with the Design View but still not able to do it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in css

```
#Button1{
position: fixed;
margin-left: ...px;
margin-top:...px;
opicity:0.1;
z-index:100;
}
```

and than you can add jquery to add event handler to it

Comment: sadly but not working, the button goes transparent but not visible